# Problem with FromZval<'_> is not implemented

Tags: php, rust, php-extension

I'm quite new to Rust, so forgive me if I ask a naive question.
I've written an experimental library, named mogul, that I try to bind to PHP using [ext-php-rs](https://crates.io/crates/ext-php-rs). And I meet a problem I don't understand.
When I try to compile, Cargo tells me :

```bash
the trait `FromZval<'_>` is not implemented for `MogulHl`
```

Here is the binding code (actually, my last try):

```rust
#![cfg_attr(windows, feature(abi_vectorcall))]
use ext_php_rs::prelude::*;
use mogul::*;

#[php_class]
pub struct MogulHl {
    mogul: MogulHandler,
}

#[php_impl]
impl MogulHl {
    pub fn allow_merge(original: MogulHl, challenger: MogulHl) -> PhpResult<()> {
        match mogul_allow_update(&original.mogul, &challenger.mogul) {
            Ok(()) => Ok(()),
            Err(MogulError::ChallengerOlderThanOriginal) => {
                Err(PhpException::default("Challenger older than the original".into()))
            } ,
            Err(MogulError::Conflict) => {
                Err(PhpException::default("Conflict between the two versions".into()))
            },
            Err(MogulError::IdenticalVersions) => {
                PhpResult::Err(PhpException::default("Identical versions".into()))
            },
            Err(MogulError::NotVersionsOfTheSameObject) => {
                PhpResult::Err(PhpException::default("Versions of different objects".into()))
            },
        }
    }
}

#[php_module]
pub fn get_module(module: ModuleBuilder) -> ModuleBuilder {
    module
}
```

Can anyone help me with this ?

UPDATE:
It seems that moving my function declaration to

```rust
pub fn allow_merge(original: &MogulHl, challenger: &MogulHl) ->
```

solved the problem, but I do not really understand why...

Comment: Reading the error message, I assume you must implement the `FromZval` trait in order for #[php_impl] tow ork.

Comment: Sorry @IMSoP ,I'm using [ext-php-rs](https://crates.io/crates/ext-php-rs). And [some one there helps me to solve my problem](https://github.com/davidcole1340/ext-php-rs/issues/160#issuecomment-1273346773), but stayed short on explanation.